# Folder with 1300 png files into html images list

Tags: c++, html, image, file, automation

I've got folder with about 1300 png icons. What I need is html file with all of them inside like:

```
<img src="path-to-image.png" alt="file name without .png" id="file-name-without-.png" class="icon"/>
```

Its easy as hell but with that number of files its pure waste of time to do it manually. Have you any ideas how to automate it?

Comment: Just use Javascript function to load all image file.

Comment: it'd be super easy to write a console app in C# to spit an html file that does that

Comment: Are you on linux? imagemagick can do this without any programming

Comment: use javascript in the html code save all the image sources in an array then call it tho show them or even use jquery there would be less coding involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it just once, then do a "dir" or "ls" and redirect it to a file, then use an editor with macro-ability like notepad++ to record modifying a single line like you desire, then hit play macro for the remainder of the file.  If it's dynamic, use PHP.

Comment: accidentally I've used windows dir command to do it. http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000772.htm - and then just modified text file with it with macros. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use C++ to do this.  I would use vi, honestly, because running regular expressions repeatedly is all that is needed for this.

But young an do this in C++.  I would start with a plan text file with all the file names generated by Dir or ls on the command prompt.

Then write code that takes a line of input and turns it into a line formatted the way you want.  Test this and get it working on a single line first.

The RE engine of C++ is probably overkill (and is not all that well supported in compilers), but substr and basic find and replace is all you need.  Is there a string library you are familiar with?  std::string would do.

To generate the file name without PNG, check the last four characters and see if they exist and are .PNG (if not report an error).  Then strip them.  To remove dashes, copy characters to a new string but if you are reading a dash write a space.  Everything else is just string concatenation.